# Golang: how to handle reverse proxy client disconnect

Tags: go, handler, reverse-proxy

Go **[httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy)** is known to automatically cancel proxying requests on client disconnect. This is implemented using **[http.CloseNotifier](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CloseNotifier)** functionality. My question is - how can I handle client disconnect i.e. execute some callback action? Should I use **[http.Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)** context like the following?

```
select {
case <-r.Context().Done(): {
    //Some action
}
default:
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? Are you trying to detect when the reverse proxy has detected the client disconnect? The docs state exactly when `Request.Context` is canceled: "the context is canceled when the ServeHTTP method returns", which of course will happen after a client disconnects, but not always be caused by a disconnect.

Comment: Yes, my question is - will context be canceled in case of reverse proxy? From the code it's not clear.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking besides what is documented -- the context is canceled when ServeHTTP returns. Maybe looking at the current code rather than go1.7 will answer your question, which has been updated to use the Context interface rather than the deprecated CancelRequest method.